# Great delay in response time in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

I have a database in mongodb it's contain to collection
Within this collection about 200,000 document
I deal with this database through : NodeJs + Express + Socket.io
These are results "mongotop" commend

```
                           ns      total       read    write    2019-10-20T13:03:03+03:00
             root_lig***.users    87461ms    75428ms    12033ms  <---- this take long time to response
  caf*************.imagesHash      691ms      691ms      0ms
     caf***************.users      155ms      102ms     53ms
    caf**************.reader        7ms        7ms      0ms
               Sa**.messages        0ms        0ms      0ms
                  Sa**.movie        0ms        0ms      0ms
                  Sa**.users        0ms        0ms      0ms
          admin.system.roles        0ms        0ms      0ms
          admin.system.users        0ms        0ms      0ms
        admin.system.version        0ms        0ms      0ms
```

There are about 200 users in real time
How to minimize this time

"server.js"

```
mongo.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err
    mongoUsers = res.db("root_li***").collection("users");
    require('./socket.js')(server, mongoUsers)
    require('./routing.js')(express, app, mongoUsers);

})
```

Comment: are you loading all the users at once?

Comment: I call the " mongo.connect " function in the main  , when the server is start .

Comment: so it is one time delay?

Comment: should I create a connection with mongo in socket.io on every connect with socket.io and close the db in disconnect function in socket.io?

Comment: Noh. it is not recommended. You should authenticate a single user and then create a connection.

Comment: Do you have a link with an example?

Comment: I doubt. You should break the problem in parts and resolve it in steps.